# How to change UIImage color?

Tags: ios, swift, image, image-processing, uiimage

I'd like to change the color of every pixel of any UIImage to a specific color *(all pixel should get the same color)*:

[image: img]

[image]

... so of course I could **just loop trough every pixel** of the UIImage and set it's **red, green and blue** property to `0` to achieve a black-color look.

But obviously this is not a effective way to recolor an image and I'm pretty sure there are several more effective methods achieving this instead of looping trough EVERY single pixel of the image.

---

```
func recolorImage(image: UIImage, color: String) -> UIImage {
    let img: CGImage = image.cgImage!
    let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: img.width, height: img.height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4 * img.width, space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)!
    context.draw(img, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: img.width, height: img.height))
    let data = context.data!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
    for i in 0..<img.height {
        for j in 0..<img.width {
           // set data[pixel] ==> [0,0,0,255]
        }
    }
   let output = context.makeImage()!
   return UIImage(cgImage: output)
 }
```

Ayn help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Why not just create a pure coloured image with the same size as the original?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the purpose here, but why even start with the original image? Just create a new image of the same size filled with the desired color.

Comment: Another more efficient way is to use a larger data type instead of `byte`.. use `int`. You'd have fewer loops and it'd set 4 bytes at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every pixel of the original image will be the same color, the result image is not dependent on the pixels of the original image. Your method actually just needs the size of the image and then creates a new image with that size, that is filled with one single color.

```
func recolorImage(image: UIImage, color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    let size = image.size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

Comment: this assumes the fill color alpha is 100% opaque

Comment: @LeoDabus Judging from how OP worded the question, I think this is indeed the case: "...and set it's **red, green and blue** property to 0 to achieve a black-color look."